# Why my Android notification's setTicker doesn't work?

Tags: android

my code is below:

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setContentTitle("nothing")
                        .setContentText("nothing").setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setTicker("help help help:)")
                        .setContentInfo("nothing")
                        .build();
                manager.notify(1, notification);
```

When I run this, "help help help:)" didn't appear.

Answer (score 2):

TickerText will only appear on phone before Android 5.0 (L)

Extracted from Documentation :

> Text that summarizes this notification for accessibility services. As
>   of the L release, this text is no longer shown on screen, but it is
>   still useful to accessibility services (where it serves as an audible
>   announcement of the notification's appearance).

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#tickerText